# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_6_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape

Tags: python, keras

I'm receiving this error from Keras:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_6_input to have 3 dimensions,      but got array with shape (55, 72)
```

on

```
model.fit(X.values, Y.values, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=16,verbose=0)
```

This is my code:

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=X.values.shape),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X.values, Y.values, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=16,verbose=0)
```

X has a shape of (55, 72)

How can I fix this and what is dense_6_input?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Dense(32, input_shape=X.values.shape)
```

Don't set the input_shape to just the shape of the input values array, as the input_shape does not contain the samples dimension. What you want should be:

```
Dense(32, input_shape=(72,)),
```

Then you should be able to call fit without issues.